# How do i fix CSS issue of an Angular Web Component in React Application?

Tags: reactjs, angular, material-ui, angular-material, web-component

I have a simple React Application and I imported an Angular Web Component with some widget from Angular Material UI(Buttons/Tables/RadioButtons). When running this React Application, the Angular Web Component's functionality like the buttons/tables/radio works just fine. However, the styling/animations of the Angular Material UI don't seem to be working at all.

Here's some screenshot of my issue:

[The radio button that is initially in the Angular Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT388.png)

[The radio button after it is imported as an Angular Web Component and place inside a React Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iznv8.png)

Would appreciate any React or Angular experts for advice. :)

Comment: There is probably conflicting CSS in your React app.  If you right click on the radio buttons in each app and inspect the element, Chrome (and other browsers) will show what CSS styles are getting applied to that element.

Comment: Hi @cjd82187, yes that is possible. 
However i indeed went ahead and right click to inspect, but the thing is because the css are actually from @angular/material/radio , so when i put this Angular Web Component inside of the React Application, it doesn't seems to be reading any @angular/material/radio properties at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to find a solution for this question i posted.
Link a css to your component js file and add the following line in that css.

Example:

Angular.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./angular3.css";



export default class Angular3 extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <your-custom-element-tag></your-custom-element-tag>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

angular3.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```